# SQLite size limit and performance

Tags: windows, sqlite, mac-os-x

I already studied some databases like **MySQL** but I never professionally work with databases. I am working on a project and we intend to use **SQLite** (for some reasons: small, lightweight, fast, among others), then I have some questions about it:

1. **SQLite** support how many gigabytes of data? Is there a limit? (I will have some huge data tables (e.g. 18 columns X 80.000 rows) for each user)
2. Is it fast to read a lot of data? (e.g. 18 columns X 80.000 rows)
3. There is any other relevant information I need to know about **SQLite**? (Note: I will use it on **Windows** and **OS X**)

**Extra information**:

The software I am working on is a data analysis software, and I just need to use the DB to save the data collected from the users using some sensors.

I am using **Qt 5.3.2** (**C++**) on the project.

Comment: I didn't understand how you are going to get to Gigabytes

Comment: I'm not saying I'm going to get to Gigabytes, I'm just asking if it is possible, if there's a "size" limit.

Comment: P.s. 80K rows is a very small set. Processing it would take fractions of a second.

Comment: Great, this is a good thing. Thanks Dudu Markovitz.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is suitable for storing data locally in user's Machine.

On Database size limit, maximum database size of 140 terabytes.

On reading data SQLite support index so you can think of having indexes based on your select query.

you can read more about it from below link:

https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm